# Replicating Adobe's 'Scan & OCR'

Tags: python, adobe, pypdf

To whom it may concern,

I have been able to process a .pdf containing scanned documents to a satisfactory degree using Python's PyPDF2.PdfReader method. Specifically, I have been able to use Python's PyPDF2.PdfReader method to convert the .pdf contents to a string and then process that string using regular expressions. Below is the code capturing my process.

### Step 1: Take original .pdf document which contains scanned documents and modify it by applying
Adobe's 'Scan and OCR' capability.

### Step 2: Code

```py
import PyPDF2
reader1 = PyPDF2.PdfReader('MyDocument.pdf') #====> This is ingesting the .pdf document which has 
                                                    resulted after modifying the original .pdf using Adobe's 'Scan and OCR' 
mytext1 = reader1.pages[0].extract_text()
```

---

However, as shown in the code above, the input to my process is the .pdf document resulting AFTER I have modified the original using Adobe's 'Scan & OCR' to process the original (ie after applying Step 1). Does anyone know a way to use Python in order to faithfully replicate this 'Scan & OCR' modification captured in Step 1?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look at PyMuPDF, which contains the Tesseract-OCR code to dynamically invoke OCR as or when required.

Comment: Jorj McKie; thanks. It seems that, indeed, PyMuPDF is the way to go.

Comment: You can use tesseract directly as well